# Android Properties not Writing to File

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Currently working on a project where I need to utilize a `Java Properties class`. To do this, I have a `Config class`. This is a `Singleton class` for use throughout the rest of the program.
 The code for it is below:

```
public class Config {

private static Config instance = new Config();
public Properties prop = new Properties();

static {
    instance.readConfig();
}

private Config () {

}

public void readConfig() {

    try {
        URL url = instance.getClass().getResource("/conf");

        prop.load(url.openStream());

        prop.setProperty("me","cool");

        url = instance.getClass().getResource("/config.properties");
        OutputStream out = url.openConnection().getOutputStream();
        prop.store(out, "Config file");
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Config", "Failed to create properly initialized config class");
    }
}

public static Config getInstance() {

    return instance;
}

public String getProperty (String key) {
    return prop.getProperty(key);
}
}
```

The code executes, I know that for a fact, but all 100 lines of the conf file are not represented in the `config.properties` file. The `config.properties` file is blank after execution. How do I get this code to actually read the data from conf by Properties and then store it into config.properties? Both files are in the assets directory of the Android Eclipse project. A sample key/value pair from conf is: 
    FREE=free

Any help would be very appreciated! I've been stuck on this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if and how the `Properties` class work with Android. But, why don't use `SharedPreferences` instead?

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaulSharedPreferences();
prefs.edit().putString("key", "myval").commit()
```

Internally, `SharedPreferences` are stored as an xml in the app dir.